# How to know how many cpu time and other resource consumed by a function?

Tags: php

Don't need accurate, just approximately. Then I can know the performance of this function.

Comment: and in general: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=profiling+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't need accurate, just approximately.

You could use [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). Otherwise profile with [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

> Then I can know the performance of this function.

Relative to what?

What sort of thing are you trying to measure? Donald Knuth once said something about optimisation...